what is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED in arm a-profile manual
I am reading a arm a-profile manual and in some sentences they say something like

The level of reliability, availability, and serviceability in any
implementation, and which parts of the system include RAS, are
IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED.
Fault prevention and fault removal are two techniques for handling
faults. Fault prevention and fault removal mechanisms are
IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED.

I don't understand what is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED. Is this some state?
I am a beginner and trying to understand things. Please help.

The document you are reading is a specification. There are many possible implementations of this specification.  "Implementation defined" means that whoever is designing the chip (or writing the emulation software) can make whatever decision they want.
In the text above, there may be robust fault prevent, or there may be no fault prevention at all.  Both are legitimate implementations of the specification.

And there should have been a glossary in the document explaining the term. I was surprised that I couldn't find it.

so, is this like when we calculate precision i.e if we want we can calculate more or we can stop, both are right

The term implementation defined is recursive for the ARM A-profile, so there is no need for a glossary, just a stack overflow.  In the context of ARM, a generic profile maybe  implementation defined, however, when you look at a specific CPU and/or SOC, the details maybe defined.  So, this is an architecture wide statement (for all A-Profile devices).  If you are 'coding' to the widest class of processors (compiler, etc.) you can not rely on the behaviour.

@FrankYellin: It is in the glossary, page 12924 in version J.a.  "Means that the behavior is not architecturally defined, but must be defined and documented by individual
implementations."

I get the impression that this might be more of a language question. Do you understand the difference between a specification and an implementation?

Still the concept is overloaded.  You can have the 'A-profile' and the some 'Cortex-A123' or whatever hard core/IP ARM gives.  Then you can have strapping, parameters, configuration to the Core which the SOC vendor implements.  Typically the last ones are 'cache size', etc.  However, in the context of the 'A-profile' and developers intending to develop to this level, it can lead to a morass of documents to look at.  For instance, someone trying to do lock free STL or something like that; mainly the term 'implementation defined' is an extreme pain for compiler and library developers.

The architecture documentation defines a specific arm architecture.  As in this add instruction must be this specific machine code.  Arm defines an architecture then it implements one or more products based on that architecture.  So arm may choose to implement something from the architecture differently for each product.  Then arm sells these products to chip vendors, who implement a chip that includes purchased IP from arm and others.  Some of these implementation choices are in the compiling of that ip, and some are logic the chip vendor has to provided.

implement differently if defined in the spec as implementation defined.  Sometimes it is a backward thing in that arm itself went off and made some implementations before publishing anything to the rest of us.  (often that lands in the "undefined behavior", where it may work exactly a known way but each core doesnt match).
